# How to sample from a Gamma distribution with shape not integer

Tags: probability-distributions, gamma-function, sampling

I'm looking for an effective method to sample from a *Gamma distribution* that has the **shape** parameter **not integer**.

However, I found everywhere the method to sample from a Gamma with an integer shape (that is as a matter of fact an Erlang distribution).

I found this [paper](http://www.stanford.edu/~jhuang11/research/dirichlet/p407-fishman.pdf) about an method for sampling from a Gamma. Unfortunately, I don't understand how to implement it!

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See Devroye "[Non-Uniform Random Variate Generation](http://www.nrbook.com/devroye/)" Section IX.3.2 (it is freely available online). Several algorithms are explained in detail there with pseudo-code, so it will be quick to code.

-- Monseigneur Myriel

Comment: You are welcome!